# Use jQuery.queue instead of setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-transitions, settimeout, jquery-queue

I want to append an element to the DOM and then add a class with transition to apply a sliding effect. Currently I'm using `setInterval()` with delay of `0`, otherwise transition won't happen ([demo](http://jsbin.com/ejECuREF/1/edit?js,output)):

```
var $block = $('<div/>', {class: 'block'});

$('body').append($block);

setTimeout(function () {
    $block.addClass('shifted');
}, 0);
```

I want to utilise [`jQuery.queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) instead, but with my current approach it doesn't work: appending the element and adding the class happen at once, so no transition is shown.

```
$('body')
    .append($block)
    .queue(function () {
        $block.addClass('shifted');
    });
```

Comment: `class` is a reserved word in JS, so your object literal should use a string as a key (i.e. `{'class': 'block'}`).

Comment: [Reserved Words actually only apply to Identifiers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words#Reserved_word_usage), and property name is an Indentifier. It shouldn't cause any problems by the spec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a timeout is required to make the animation happen, then you should add a [`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/):

```
$('body')
    .append($block)
    .delay(0)
    .queue(function (next) {
        $block.addClass('shifted');
        next(); //don't forget to dequeue so that the rest of the queue can run
    });
```

`.delay()` is really just a convenience method for:

```
.queue(function (n) {
    setTimeout(n, duration);
});
```

If you don't call `delay` (or queue a timeout), the fx queue will execute immediately, which defeats the purpose of queuing `$block.addClass('shifted')`.

Comment: Maybe drop the `queue` then? Just do `append` - `delay` - `addClass`?

Comment: `addClass` does not add itself to the fx queue. My point is that, without the `delay` function being called, your code is running identically to `$block.appendTo('body').addClass('shifted');`. To make it run the `addClass` after a timeout, you need to have a delay somehow.